# How to compile MATLAB MEX file using Mingw-w64 and Intel MKL

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, mingw-w64, intel-mkl

Could someone with experience help me to accomplish the above noble objective please?

After so many hours (rather days) and ways of trying and searching the internet, the frustration has accumulated in me that I decided to turn to the SO community. I hope that a working solution will help also others in such a situation.

My setup:

- Windows 10
- MATLAB R2019b

  - Intel MKL for calling the compiled mex files in MATLAB, this particular version of MATLAB uses:

    - 'Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2018.0.3 Product Build 20180406 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications, CNR branch AVX'
- MinGW64 Compiler (C++) for mex file compilation, more precisely:

  - x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev
- Two source cpp files

  - Although they are not important now, as the issue does not lie here. (For information only: these files correctly compile with OpenBLAS but this is out of scope.)

I try to use the built-in mex command in MATLAB plus linking the correct Intel MKL libraries as shown below; however, I do not mind using any other setup for compilation. The only restriction what I have to respect is to stay on a Windows 10 platform.

`mex -g -DMKL_ILP64 '-IC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\include' '-LC:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win' main.cpp sub.cpp  -lmkl_intel_ilp64.lib -lmkl_sequential.lib -lmkl_core.lib`

Attempt to compile leads to many error messages as shown at the bottom. This is only a truncated version of the original error message as it would otherwise exceed SO's limitation on allowed character length per question.

Most of errors are either `undefined references` either to

> __security_check_cookie

or

> __GSHandlerCheck

I highly appreciate any help, hint or suggestion. Thank you in advance.

````
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Error using mex
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemm.obj):(.text[dgemm]+0x194): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemm.obj):(.text[dgemm]+0x2a0): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemm.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemm.obj):(.xdata+0x3c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dsyrk.obj):(.text[dsyrk]+0x14c): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dsyrk.obj):(.text[dsyrk]+0x215): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dsyrk.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dsyrk.obj):(.xdata+0x3c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_ddot.obj):(.text[ddot]+0x63): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_ddot.obj):(.text[ddot]+0x125): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_ddot.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_ddot.obj):(.xdata+0x30): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemv.obj):(.text[dgemv]+0x15b): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemv.obj):(.text[dgemv]+0x248): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemv.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgemv.obj):(.xdata+0x3c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgetrf.obj):(.text[dgetrf]+0xe0): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgetrf.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dpotrf.obj):(.text[dpotrf]+0xdc): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dpotrf.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgesv.obj):(.text[dgesv]+0xc5): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgesv.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgetri.obj):(.text[dgetri]+0xb9): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dgetri.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dpotri.obj):(.text[dpotri]+0xa7): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dpotri.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dtrtri.obj):(.text[dtrtri]+0xb4): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib(_dtrtri.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files
(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_print_verbose_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_print_verbose_info]+0x36b):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_print_verbose_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined
reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_read_threads_env]+0x612):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files
(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[count_cores_impl_win32_or_ver_6_0_or_less]+0x12):
undefined reference to `__chkstk'
C:\Program Files
(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[count_cores_impl_win32_or_ver_6_0_or_less]+0x860):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_mpi_get_ppn]+0xaf):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_ncpus]+0x12):
undefined reference to `__chkstk'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_ncpus]+0x11d1):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files
(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_ncorespercpu]+0x43b): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_ht]+0x43c):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x1c): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files
(x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_nlogicalcores]+0x43b): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_sequential.lib(mkl_threading_omp_no_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_dsecnd]+0xc6): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_cpu_frequency]+0x421): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0x34): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0xa8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_second]+0xcd): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_clocks_frequency]+0x64): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_max_cpu_frequency]+0xaa): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(dsecnd.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(xerbla.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_xerbla]+0x62): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(xerbla.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(xerbla.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_check_ptr]+0x3c): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(xerbla.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(xerbla.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_default_xerbla]+0x13c): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(xerbla.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_set_memory_limit]+0xcb): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_allocate]+0x5c): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_malloc]+0x42): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mm_account_ptr_by_tid..0]+0x232): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_deallocate]+0x621): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_free]+0x216): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_free_buffers]+0x344): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_thread_free_buffers]+0x2bc):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mm_account_ptr_by_tid]+0x378): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_mem_stat]+0x239): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_realloc]+0x639): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_jit_alloc]+0x5b): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_jit_free]+0x22d): undefined reference
to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mm_cleanup_thread_cbk]+0x3a7): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x14): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_fast_mm_status]+0x39): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_memory_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_verbose.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_verbose]+0xb8): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_verbose.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_verbose.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_verbose_mode]+0x4c): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_verbose.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_verbose.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_verbose_output_file_mode]+0x47): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_verbose.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_cpu_detect]+0x50): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_cpu_type]+0x293): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_enable_instructions]+0x30e):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x18): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_is_sse4_2_enabled]+0x141):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_is_avx_enabled]+0x141):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_is_avx2_enabled]+0x141):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_is_avx512_enabled]+0x141):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_is_avx512_mic_enabled]+0x141):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(load_dll_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0x8): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_cbwr_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_cbwr_get]+0xa1): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_cbwr_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_cbwr_static_patched.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_cbwr_get_nolock]+0xa1):
undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_cbwr_static_patched.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to
`__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_getversion.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_version_string]+0x2f3): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_getversion.obj):(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_getversion.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_version_string_c]+0x273): undefined
reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_getversion.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_msg_support.obj):(.text[mkl_serv_get_msg]+0x218): undefined reference to
`__security_check_cookie'
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.185\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win\mkl_core.lib(mkl_msg_support.obj):(.xdata+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```
````

Comment: You cannot mix .lib files for MSVC and for MinGW’s GCC. If I understand correctly, they use a different format. This is the source of illegal directives and missing symbols. So either build everything with one compiler or with the other, including the MKL. If you downloaded a precompiled MKL, it is likely compatible with MSVC, but not with MinGW.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your comment/answer. That's what I was afraid of. But wait, does it mean that the MinGW64 compiler with MATLAB is not suitable with Intel MKL on Windows at all? As far as I know, Intel does not support this compiler with its MKL product.
Or how is it possible to compile "from scratch" everything included = C++ source files + MinGW64 + Intel MKL on Windows?

Comment: Does the MKL come with DLLs, or is everything static libs? DLLs are compatible across all compilers on Windows, because they follow a well-defined ABI. Static libs are just collections of object files, and how those are defined depends on the tools you use. If there's a DLL for MKL, then link to that in your `mex` command.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks again. The file extension of all the files in the relevant MKL folder is only .lib, so they must be static libraries. However, Intel uses an interesting naming convention as there are files whose names (but not file extension after the dot) contain the word "DLL" such as mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib, mkl_sequential_dll.lib, mkl_core_dll.lib. The Intel MKL Link Line Advisor recommends to use them for dynamic compilation, even though they are static libraries with .lib extension as I described before. Tricky enough.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Are you 100% sure that the compatibility of DLLs hold for all compilers on Windows? The reason why I am asking that because I always thought that is only in the case when the source code of those DLLs was written in "pure C", but for C++ the compatibility may not hold in every case.

Comment: Different compilers can mangle C++ symbols differently. I'm not that familiar with Windows, but I thought Windows had a stable C++ ABI as well (this is definitely not the case on Linux). It is possible that I'm wrong there. If the DLL exports "C" symbols (a C++ compiler can do so as well) then it'll be compatible across compilers. I would presume that MKL has a C interface, so that it can be used from many different environments and tools.

Comment: [This page](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-math-kernel-library-system-requirements.html) seems to indicate that MKL requires an Intel compiler or the PGI compiler. The page doesn't indicate that MKL is compatible with either GCC or MSVC on Windows. I find this rather hard to believe...

Comment: Relevant: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/MKL-with-MinGW64-compiler/td-p/802929 -- it might be impossible what you're trying to do!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your detailed answers. I highly appreciate your time and effort. It looks very like that I have to change the MinGW64 compiler because trying to compile with it seems to be a dead-end.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Also thanks for the intel community link. Oh, yeah I have read that before, and there is a relatively newer one (from 2018) below basically confirming the same status quo.
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've just checked the official Mathworks site which compilers they support for mex file compilation in case of the R2019 version. Link below. 
https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/system-requirements-release-2019b-supported-compilers.pdf
Highly likely that I have to compile with Intel's compiler in this case.
I am wondering why this process and other things are often much easier on Linux..
Btw, I checked your personal site. Great and impressive stuff what you are doing! I am amazed!